docker build --ssh default doesn't mount ssh key
I am trying to run following docker build command
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 BUILDKIT_PROGRESS=plain docker build --ssh default=~/.ssh/id_rsa -t dev-build .

and have following command for installing private package using composer in Dockerfile

RUN mkdir -p -m 0700 ~/.ssh && ssh-keyscan bitbucket.org >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN --mount=type=ssh git clone git@bitbucket.org:devteam/db.git

But its failing pass the SSH key. I can clone the same repo using the same ssh key locally.
#7 [stage-0 4/5] RUN --mount=type=ssh git clone git@bitbucket.org:devteam/db.git
#7 0.309 Cloning into 'db'...
#7 0.476 Host key verification failed.
#7 0.477 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
#7 0.477
#7 0.477 Please make sure you have the correct access rights
#7 0.477 and the repository exists.
#7 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c git clone git@bitbucket.org:devteam/db.git" did not complete successfully: exit code: 128
------
 > [stage-0 4/5] RUN --mount=type=ssh git clone git@bitbucket.org:devteam/db.git:
0.309 Cloning into 'db'...
0.476 Host key verification failed.
0.477 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
0.477
0.477 Please make sure you have the correct access rights
0.477 and the repository exists.
------

I am on Docker version 26.1.4, build 5650f9b
Any help on this what I am missing here ?

Did you have a key with passphrase ?

my key doesn't have passphrase

  RUN --mount=type=ssh \   ssh -q -T git@gitlab.com  .  Check https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/reference.md#run---mounttypessh

"Host key verification failed" implies authentication with your user key wasn't even attempted, so this gives no info whether your user key is good or bad. My only idea how host-key fails after ssh-keyscan is that it created authorized_keys with too-loose permissions (perhaps allowing group access?); check that.

Maybe you could also add RUN ssh-keygen -R bitbucket.org && curl https://bitbucket.org/site/ssh >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts  before  mount

the SSH key isn’t being passed correctly during the Docker build.
Enable BuildKit in Docker:
Edit /etc/docker/daemon.json and add:
{
    "features": {
        "buildkit": true
    }
}

Restart Docker:
sudo systemctl restart docker

Update your Dockerfile:
Make sure your Dockerfile uses the SSH mount correctly:
Dockerfile
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.4
FROM your_base_image

RUN mkdir -p -m 0700 ~/.ssh && ssh-keyscan bitbucket.org >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN --mount=type=ssh git clone git@bitbucket.org:devteam/db.git

Build with SSH key:
Use this build command:
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 BUILDKIT_PROGRESS=plain docker build --ssh default=$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa -t dev-build .

Check SSH key permissions:
Ensure the SSH key has the right permissions:
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Add SSH key to the agent:
If using Docker Desktop, add your SSH key to the agent:
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa

